# How to save attachments

Tags: 8.0, email, attachments

In Windows Phone 8, is there a way to save an attachment that is in an email to the phone or up to SkyDrive so I can view it at my leisure after my emails are cleared out?

In particular, someone sent me a large PDF file as an attachment to an email. I have the Microsoft free PDF Reader app. But email gives me no way to save attachments. And the PDF Reader does not have a save option either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There does indeed not appear to be any sharing nor saving options in Microsoft’s PDF Reader application.

However, every PDF you open with it is stored for some period in the application itself. If you open the PDF Reader application on it’s own you will see all the PDFs that you have recently opened with it. Exactly how this work and for how long they are stored is unknown. I tested with an attachment to an email that I deleted and the PDF remained accessible even after deleting the email. As this feature is so loosely defined, you should not rely on it for important documents.

I cannot suggest any alternative than using a PC and keep checking the App Marketplace for a better PDF reader alternative.

Comment: I see a lot of people complaining in the reviews that the reader never deletes the PDFs.

Comment: PDF Reader has since added sharing via sky drive [see this image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/O7cgY.png)